# Getting and Verifying Image Headers Expires

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-expires

I am working on SEO and need to verify that Image Headers Expires is working. Both modules for expires and headers are installed and enabled.

Any ideas?

The .htaccess file has this in it

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

I have added this to both the wordpress/ directory and the wordpress/wp-content/ directory.

And yet the SEO tool is saying "Your server is not using expires header for your images."

to test using curl I have done

```
Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2023 04:31:01 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.jaycocioservices.com/about
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: _Aside:_ "Both modules for expires and headers are installed and enabled." - This does not use mod_headers.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `ExpiresActive` directive to enable the generation of the relevant `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers.

You don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper - this is only going to mask the error if mod_expires is not installed.

You don't need the `ExpiresByType image/jpg ...` directive since the correct mime-type is `image/jpeg`, which you already have in the directive that follows.

You don't need to repeat these directives in both the `/wordpress` and `/wordpress/wp-content` directories. Placing these directives in the root `.htaccess` file should be sufficient and naturally applies to all subdirectories.

Also consider setting an `ExpiresDefault` directive for all other mime-types.

For example:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 days"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
```

> to test using curl I have done
>
> ```
> Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2023 04:31:01 GMT
> Server: Apache
> Location: https://www.jaycocioservices.com/about
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
> ```

That looks like a redirect response (due to the presence of the `Location` header), which perhaps should not be cached anyway (or left to the browser default in the case of a 301). Make sure you are requesting the canonical URL to test.

This (`/about` text/html) is also for a request not covered by your existing mod_expires directives. You need to be requesting an image, CSS or JS file.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So my apologies I did not have it in my comments but I do have the ExpiresActive On. I will drop the IfModule, and I drop the jpg mime line. I also added the ExpiresDefault as you suggested. Do I need to add anything for the Cache-Control?

Comment: @Jay `ExpiresByType` sets both the `Expires` and `Cache-Control: max-age` headers. The `Cache-Control` header is the important one.

Comment: Ok I think I have it now. My problem is Rank Math is still reporting that there is not using image header expires.

Comment: @Jay What do you see in the HTTP response headers (browser with cleared cache or CURL) when you request one of these assets? (I tried the domain you mentioned above, but this is not resolving for me currently?)